# Bindings for pretty printer class instances

Tags: haskell

How to create a binding for the following instance? I am looking, at this point, for any binding solution that will compile, just so I can begin to understand my errors. My entire code is:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstrainedClassMethods #-}
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

module Tagless where

import Data.Text.IO as T
import Data.Text.Prettyprint.Doc.Render.Text 
 
data Exp = B Bool 
    | MyInt Int 
    
data Doc ann 
 
class Pretty a where
    pretty :: Show a => a -> Doc ann 
    prettyList :: [a] -> Doc ann 
    
instance Pretty Bool where
    pretty :: Bool -> Doc ann
    prettyList :: [Bool] -> Doc ann
```

I have tried the following and variations, but I get multiple mismatched types. 1) Since B is a Bool Exp, why can it not be used considering pretty is expecting a Bool? 2) How can I create a binding to match Doc?

```
instance Pretty Bool where
    pretty :: Bool -> Doc ann
    prettyList :: [Bool] -> Doc ann
    pretty (B e1) = e1 
    prettyList [B e1] = e1
```

I am using package https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter-1.1.1/docs/Data-Text-Prettyprint-Doc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redefining the `Doc` type and `Pretty` class, so first you should delete the `data` and `class` definitions and use the ones imported from `Data.Text.Prettyprint.Doc` (or `Prettyprinter` in more recent versions of the library). Next, you want to make an `instance` of `Pretty` for `Exp`, whereas currently you’re writing an instance for `Bool` (which already exists):

```
instance Pretty Bool where
instance Pretty Exp where
```

Next, you only need to define the `pretty` function, not `prettyList`, and your `pretty` definition should have type `Exp -> Doc ann`, not `Bool -> Doc ann`:

```
instance Pretty Exp where
    pretty :: Bool -> Doc ann
    pretty :: Exp -> Doc ann
    prettyList :: [Bool] -> Doc ann
```

You can define `pretty` by pattern-matching on your `Exp` type, and defining the pretty-printing you want for each constructor. For example, if you just want to show the Booleans and integers with their default `Pretty` instances, just call `pretty` on the values extracted from the `Exp`:

```
    pretty exp = case exp of
        B bool -> pretty bool    -- (1) 
        MyInt int -> pretty int  -- (2)
```

Note that the calls to `pretty` at (1) and (2) are *different* instances: the first is `pretty :: Bool -> Doc ann`, the second is `pretty :: Int -> Doc ann`. You build up the pretty-printing instance for a type by combining smaller components, using `pretty` or combinators like `hcat`/`hsep`/`vcat`/`<+>`/`indent`/… from `prettyprinter`. So, putting it all together:

```
instance Pretty Exp where
    pretty :: Exp -> Doc ann
    pretty exp = case exp of
        B bool -> pretty bool
        MyInt int -> pretty int
```

Or, in equational style instead of using `case`:

```
    pretty (B bool) = pretty bool
    pretty (MyInt int) = pretty int
```

> Since B is a Bool Exp, why can it not be used considering pretty is expecting a Bool?

`B` is a *constructor* of type `Bool -> Exp`, so an *expression* like `B e1` makes a value of type `Exp` by wrapping `e1`, which must be a `Bool`; similarly, the *pattern* `B e1` matches a `B` constructor, and extracts its field `e1`, which is also of type `Bool`. So when you wrote this:

```
pretty (B e1) = e1
```

What you were saying is “extract the `Bool` field and return it”, but you’re trying to return a `Bool` when a `Doc` is expected. (That is, this definition has type `Exp -> Bool`, but the signature requires `Exp -> Doc ann`.)

You may find it clearer to use `GADTSyntax` to define your data types, since it allows you to write out the type of each constructor explicitly as `FieldType1 -> … -> FieldTypeN -> TypeName`, e.g.:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTSyntax #-}

data Exp where
  B :: Bool -> Exp
  MyInt :: Int -> Exp
```

This is exactly the signature you would get by asking for the type of the constructor in GHCi:

```
> :type MyInt
MyInt :: Int -> Exp
```

Comment: This is very informative. Thank you. I tried to run your solution, and got 'Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Pretty’', so I am assuming the import did not work for me since the class was not imported, did it work for you?

Comment: @pmichaels: If you look at the docs for the package, you’ll find [`class Pretty` in the `Data.Text.Prettyprint.Doc` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter-1.1.1/docs/Data-Text-Prettyprint-Doc.html#t:Pretty), so you should import it from there. To get what I’ve used here, you could write `import Data.Text.Prettyprint.Doc (Doc, Pretty(..))`. You probably want to import other parts of the library `qualified` with an abbreviation, like `import qualified Data.Text.Prettyprint.Doc as Pretty` or `… as P` so it’s always clear where a name comes from, e.g. `Pretty.nest` / `P.nest`.

Comment: I have made some import updates and it's working now. Thanks again for the clarification.